# How to select first row that contains a formula in Excel with Python

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, openxlsx

I am trying to select the first cell that has a formula then select the entire row, copy it then hardcode it (paste special)

Here's my
[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14sVP.png). I'd like to be able to select the first #N/A - VLOOKUP formula

Here's my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
src_wb = load_workbook(file path) 
ws = src_wb["Sheet1"]
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=12):
for cell in row:
    if cell.value == None:
        print(cell.value)
```

I can't seem to find any resources so far. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, all formula’s start with ‘=‘. So I’d say just loop and stop as soon as your cell value string starts with ‘=‘